# What would it take to fix a car in a post-apocalypse?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse

In a post-apocalyptic world, monster-like creatures have taken over most of the planet, focusing mostly on hunting humans and not really focusing on destroying any existing buildings or structures except for certain areas where they build their "nests" and those that have a large amount of humans. Twenty years later, only a few clusters of humanity still remain with somewhat functioning governments, and with "towns," as in places with apartments/buildings that have somewhat functioning water and electricity and other necessities that people live in, that are scattered across what's left of America.

In this world, say a group of survivors encounters a car that hasn't been used since the apocalypse began in what's left of a house's garage. The metal has been damaged, it's tires are missing and/or damaged, but everything else, from the engine and all of its internal mechanics, are in reasonable shape, or as reasonable as car that hasn't been used in twenty years can be, and the keys are even left in the side door, though it won't start. The survivors are currently in monster-territory, but they're hidden well enough where the monsters can't find them unless they venture too far from the garage. With their only hope of escaping fast enough to lose these monsters are this car, they have to try and find some way to fix it in their current location.

Given all of this information, what would be needed to get this car working again?

Comment: This seems to be more about a story set in your world than about building the world, but you may get something usefull before it closes. Do you have tools? Replacement tyres, failing that, welding-equipment? What sort of car is it, a classic with a starting handle and magneto? Petrol, LPG, derv, electric or steam (yep, they realy existed). Is there a kitchen/chemical storehouse/petrol plant nearby. Is there anyone in the party with mechanical knowledge/skills. Even if it were not off-topic as story based, it would be off-topic as fishing for ideas and lacking sufficient details to answer.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer - and it's not a worldbuilding question. Frankly, if the car was sitting there in perfect condition after 20 years, the gas would be stale (if not evaporated), the oil would be separated sludge half-dry in the pan, and the battery would be a useless hunk of plastic and lead. And there's more depending on the type of car, location of car, level of technology, skill set of characters, yada yada yada. However, not a worldbuilding question. VTC.

Comment: They waste time trying to figure out the car.  Finally they get it started.  It is enormously loud.  They quickly shut it down, and slump on the seats, defeated.   Then they realize in the back of the barn, under a tarp, are 5 dirt bikes...

Comment: Among your problems: gasoline won't last 20 years on the shelf. Some fuels might with careful preservation, but it's unlikely you'd find any in a random person's garage.